# Failed to change service config

Tags: service, vb6

I', trying to create a service and change its configurations accourding to my needs. creation is not a problem but when I want to change service settings it fails. I want to create Interactive service. here's my code:

```
Public Function setInteractiveOption() As Boolean
    Dim hSCManager As Long
    Dim hService As Long
    hSCManager = OpenSCManager(vbNullString, vbNullString, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)

    hService = OpenService(hSCManager, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG)

    Dim result As Long
    result = ChangeServiceConfig(hService, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS Or SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, vbNull, vbNull, vbNull, vbNull, vbNull, vbNull, vbNull)


    CloseServiceHandle hService

    If result Then
        setInteractiveOption = True
    Else
        setInteractiveOption = False
    End If

End Function
```

it gives me error code 1057 - The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.

**Edit**: here is my API delaration:

```
Public Declare Function ChangeServiceConfig Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
      "ChangeServiceConfigA" (ByVal hService As Long, ByVal dwServiceType _
      As Long, ByVal dwStartType As Long, ByVal dwErrorControl As Long, ByVal _
      lpBinaryPathName As String, ByVal lpLoadOrderGroup As String, lpdwTagId _
      As Long, ByVal lpDependencies As String, ByVal lpServiceStartName As String, _
      ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal lpDisplayName As String) As Long

      Private Declare Function OpenService _
      Lib "advapi32" Alias "OpenServiceA" _
      (ByVal hSCManager As Long, ByVal lpServiceName As String, _
      ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long) As Long  

      Private Declare Function OpenSCManager _
      Lib "advapi32" Alias "OpenSCManagerA" _
      (ByVal lpMachineName As String, ByVal lpDatabaseName As String, _
      ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long) As Long
```

**`Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = &HFFFFM`**

You can download code of my project here(I downloaded orginal source from Internet):
http://www.mediafire.com/?138esmdw5tvt19q

I tested this program on XP (and failed) but in windows 7 it seems weird : I doesn't register service but changing its configuration is successful!

Comment: @wqw I posted API delarations but I don't think they're problem. I copied them from API viewer

Comment: You know `vbNull` is very different than `vbNullString`?

Comment: @wqw Thanks, That helped and handle in not 0 now but i gives me another error:__ 1057 - The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified. __ when I call ChangeServiceConfig function:(

Comment: In API declaration change `lpdwTagId As Long` to `ByVal lpdwTagId As Long` and try passing `0` instead of `vbNullString`.

Comment: Post your API constants, `SERVICE_NO_CHANGE` particularly.

Comment: @wqw I edited my post and added that constant

Comment: Checking in the SDK it should be something like `Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE As Long = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error message is complaining about the account, then start there.  You have the account parameters declared as string:

```
... ,ByVal lpServiceStartName As String, ByVal lpPassword As String
```

so you will need to use vbNullString as the value to pass.

Alternatively, redefine thjem as long:

```
..., ByVal lpServiceStartName As Long, ByVal lpPassword As Long
```

and then pass 0& as the value.

**EDIT1:**

I changed

```
Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = &HFFFF
```

to

```
Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = &HFFFFFFFF
```

and, referencing my own service that was already installed, I called setInteractiveOption and it was successful on XP Pro.  I made sure that the account of the service is setup as LocalSystem, as indicated in the MSDN.

**EDIT2:**

Here is the decalre (you must also use the constant from EDIT1)

```
Public Declare Function ChangeServiceConfig Lib "advapi32.dll" _
Alias "ChangeServiceConfigA" ( _
   ByVal hService As Long, _
   ByVal dwServiceType As Long, _
   ByVal dwStartType As Long, _
   ByVal dwErrorControl As Long, _
   ByVal lpBinaryPathName As String, _
   ByVal lpLoadOrderGroup As String, _
   ByVal lpdwTagId As String, _
   ByVal lpDependencies As String, _
   ByVal lpServiceStartName As String, _
   ByVal lpPassword As String, _
   ByVal lpDisplayName As String) As Long
```

Here is your method:

```
Public Function setInteractiveOption() As Boolean
    Dim hSCManager As Long
    Dim hService As Long
    hSCManager = OpenSCManager(vbNullString, vbNullString, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
    MsgBox "hSCManager: " & hSCManager
    hService = OpenService(hSCManager, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG)
    MsgBox "hService: " & hService
    Dim result As Long

    result = ChangeServiceConfig(hService, _
                                 SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS Or SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS, _
                                 SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, _
                                 SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString, _
                                 vbNullString)

    MsgBox "result: " & result & vbNewLine & "Error: " & Err.LastDllError

    CloseServiceHandle hService

    If result Then
        setInteractiveOption = True
    Else
        setInteractiveOption = False
    End If

End Function
```

I then added a button to call just this method to your form and it worked great.

Comment: did not help. I added my source code ,so you can download and check it!

Comment: I'll give it a try. Though the code you edited above does not do what I suggested.

Comment: The error your code was throwing was 87, invalid parameter. Change `Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = &HFFFF` to `Public Const SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = &HFFFFFFFF` and it will work.

Comment: And by work I mean it will set the interactive flag correctly as you wanted.  I suspect you might have some other issues as it incorrectly renamed my test service, but that could have been a side effect of my debugging effort.

Comment: Thanks man but I steal get same error(invalid account) what OS do you testing? I test on Windows XP and it fails

Comment: Sorry my fault it exists on 7 but fails on XP

Comment: ARe you just testing the setInteractiveOption method you listed in your question?  Changing the Interact with Desktop flag did work on XP with the edits I made.

Comment: yes, I just test that function nothing more! it's fine one windows 7 but NOT on XP ( the OS I want to launch the program )

Comment: Thanks, now it's working on both windows XP and 7. I really appreciate your help!